# Select a model instance from HTML form on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get my html form to allow me to pass the company model instance. As of now, I can pull the names of each company instance, however, what would I put into the value attibute of the option field to have it select the instance correctly?

```
<option value="what to put here?">{{Company.name}}</option>
```

I was hoping to do this through HTML forms and not Django forms as I have used AJAX to make a nice little live-updating interface.

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Contact(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["lastname"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

views.py

```
class contact_manager(ListView):
    template_name = 'crm/contact_manager.html'
    context_object_name = 'contact_manager'
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(contact_manager, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contact'] = Contact.objects.all()
        context['company_list'] = Company.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

contact_manager.html

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Company">
      <option value="">Please select a company</option>
      {% for Company in company_list %}
      <option value="{{Company.name}}">{{Company.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a unqiue identifier for each option, that links to a model instance on the backend, that is what the ID field is for (`Company.id`):

```
<option value="{{ Company.id }}">{{Company.name}}</option>
```

Then on the backend you can retrieve the model with the posted id:

```
Company.get(id=posted_id)
```

Note: `id` is by default added to your model as the primary key and is a auto incrememting integer.